# Angular HttpClient Reposnse Becomes Null in Google Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, frontend, mozilla

Why is that when a large data response(around 600+MB) is returned in client-side; the response becomes NULL in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla.

Are there any settings I need to set in order for the process to work correctly in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a limit to the size of response data that Google Chrome could handle. As a solution for this, we tried to reduce the size of the data before sending it back to the client-side; and it was able to work properly.